# How to configure create-react-kotlin-app in order to get kotlinx.serialization working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, serialization, kotlin, compiler-errors

I've been trying to get the kotlinx.serialization library working with Kotlin/JS using the create-react-kotlin-app

However, I am not so familiar with the huge nodeJS and webpack mess.
I did the following:

1) Downloaded the kotlinx.serialization library from maven repository a located it aside the nodeJS dependencies, because there is so far no any npm module for this.

2) Modified the **node_modules/@jetbrains/kotlin-webpack-plugin/plugin.js** in order to compile my library, in particular I added this row to the prepareLibraries function:

```
opts.libraries.push(opts.packagesContents[0]["_where"]+"/lib/kotlinx-serialization-runtime-js/build/classes/main/kotlinx-serialization-runtime-js.js")
```

3) Modified the last line in **node_modules/kotlin-compiler/bin/kotlinc** in order to enable the the serialization compiler plugin:

```
${JAVACMD:=java}" $JAVA_OPTS "${java_args[@]}" -cp "${kotlin_app[@]}" "${kotlin_args[@]}" -Xplugin=$KOTLIN_HOME/lib/kotlinx-serialization-compiler-plugin.jar
```

The thing is that when I run the dev server using npm start, it compiles and runs as expected, but when I run npm run build, I got the following error:

> Creating an optimized production build...
>
> Failed to compile.
>
> warning: flag is not supported by this version of the compiler: -
>   Xplugin=/home/Project/archetype-frontend-kotlin/node_modules/kotlin-compiler/lib/kotlinx-serialization-compiler-plugin.jar
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

And of course when I remove the -Xplugin argument, the application is throwing exceptions like this:

> Can't locate argument-less serializer for class Pu…h as lists, please provide serializer explicitly.

(There is an issue on GH related to this https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/278)

Thanks for any help

Comment: Could you show the code that produced this issue?

Comment: How exactly dyd you "located it aside the nodeJS dependencies"? I'm having the same struggle right now and the stuff I get from maven has different structure than the directories in "node_modules".

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I managed to make it work.

Here are the steps as I remember them:

- as suggested in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CRKA-84, did `npm eject` and added `plugin: require.resolve('kotlin-compiler/lib/kotlinx-serialization-compiler-plugin.jar'),` to `webpack-kotlin-*.js` files (after `new KotlinWebpackPlugin`).
- downloaded the compiled runtime from maven (https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlinx/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/kotlinx-serialization-runtime-js/0.9.0/) and unpacked it to `node-modules/kotlinx-serialization-runtime-js`
- hacked `kotlin-compiler.js` by adding the library path (there must be a better way!):

```
      options.libraries.join(isWindows ? ';' : ':') + ":<absolute_path_to_project>/node_modules/kotlinx-serialization-runtime-js/kotlinx-serialization-runtime-js.meta.js"
```

- copied `kotlinx-serialization-runtime-js.js` and `kotlinx-serialization-runtime-js.js.map` to `node-modules/.cache/kotlin-webpack`.

After this `yarn start` appears to be able to compile some test code that uses `kotlinx-serialization`, however, Idea fails to find where `kotlinx.serialization` module comes from.

I hope this answer inspires someone who is willing to reverse-engieer this build system to make a better fix.